# Having trouble detecting undefined objects in an array

Tags: javascript

Quick bit about my background:

- -been learning for about 3 months;
- -work in tech support for a small software company. 2 years exp.
- -a lot of knowledge is secondhand and I am still learning the basics

I am trying to create an object every second. The object is created directly to the last position of an array that remembers a set quantity of objects created before the most recent one

```
function Fruit(name, position) {
   this.name = name;
   this.position = position;
}

var showXMostRecentFruits = 20;

var fruitCounter = 0;
function generateName() {
   var name = 'Experimental Fruit' + fruitCounter;
   return name;
}

var fruitsArray = [];

function shiftFruits() {
   for (i = 0; i < showXMostRecentFruits; i++) {
      fruitsArray[i] = fruitsArray[i + 1];
}

function updateFruitPositions() {
   for (i = 0; i < showXMostRecentFruits; i++) {
      fruitsArray[i].position = i;
   }
}

var fruitTimer; //used for setting and clearing setTimeout

function createNewFruit() {
   shiftFruits();
   fruitsArray[showXMostRecentFruits - 1] = new Fruit(generateName());
   updateFruitPositions();
   fruitCounter += 1;

   fruitTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      createNewFruit();
   }, 1000);
}
```

Say the function createNewFruit() is run once

```
createNewFruit();
```

Then I try to pull some meaning from the array

```
console.log(fruitsArray[19];
```

All I get is:

```
Fruit {}
undefined
```

This issue is when I want to run a loop (see updateFruitPositions()) that updates a propery of each object in the array, an error is returned that the objects are undefined. I get that they are undefined because they are not assigned to unique variables (at least not that I'm aware of). How can I identify the objects or how can I create unique containers for them so I access them in the array?

Comment: Where is the code that actually populates your array?

Comment: createNewFruit() populates the array

Comment: run updateFruitPositions() before adding on the new fruit

Comment: @dandavis, what about when the array is partially full (the first 19 times the function runs)?

Comment: would inverting the place I put the new fruit with a .push() be better and popping off the last with a conditional be a better idea?

Comment: are you allowed to use built-in array methods like shift() and push() ? (it would make this a lot easier)

Comment: I think you're better to just create a new fruit and [*push*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7) to to the end of the array. If the length is then greater than *showXMostRecentFruits*, use [*shift*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.9) to remove the one at index 0 and shuffle them all down one. If it isn't, don't shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test whether a given element is set to something before attempting to write to one of its properties.

Instead of this...

```
for (i = 0; i < showXMostRecentFruits; i++) {
   fruitsArray[i].position = i;
}
```

Use this:

```
for (i = 0; i < showXMostRecentFruits; i++) {
   if (fruitsArray[i])
       fruitsArray[i].position = i;
}
```

You fill the array from the end, staring with element 20. Without the `if (fruitsArray[i])`, you're attempting to set `undefined.position = i` for the first 19 elements.

Comment: Thanks for your solution . I was wondering how to test the positions but undefined and an undefined object were throwing me off. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the *showFruits* function with something much more efficient:

```
function shiftFruits() {
  if (fruitsArray.length > showXMostRecentFruits) {
      fruitsArray.shift();
  }
}
```

and *updateFruitPositions* only needs to update members that exist, the length is controlled by *shiftFruits*:

```
function updateFruitPositions() {
   for (i = 0; i < fruitsArray.length; i++) {
      fruitsArray[i].position = i;
   }
}
```

or where *forEach* is supported:

```
function updateFruitPositions() {
   fruitsArray.forEach(function(fruit, i){fruit.position = i});
}
```

so it only visits members that exist. And the *createNewFruit* has:

```
fruitsArray.push(new Fruit(generateName());
```